# Insertar imagen en select option

Tags: php, imagen, select

Tengo esta función, lo que intento hacer es añadir una imagen a un option  pero no hay manera.

Decir que el valor de los campos me lo introduce bien en el select opcion pero la foto no aparece. No da ningún error la pagina, simplemente despliego el select y veo todos los campos pero no la imagen.

El motivo de querer hacer esto, es que dependiendo de si un campo está activo o no, quiero que el select tenga un icono avisando al usuario de que esa persona esta activa.

```
var ruta = "php/bombillaV.png";


    $.ajax ({
        url: "/loren/php/colab_x_usuario_token.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            objJson=JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(objJson, function(i, item) {
                //if (objJson[i].estado_col == '1'){
                    $('#idColaboradorCT').append("<option style=background:url("+ruta+") no-repeat center left; padding-left:5px; value= "+objJson[i].id+" >"+" "+objJson[i].name + " " + objJson[i].apellidos+"</option>");
                //}
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: La mejor opción será recurrir a una librería de terceros como [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/), o bien [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render) u otras... ya que los `select` son tratados de formas distintas según el navegador, entonces lo que en un cliente funciona puede que en otro no, o funcione diferente... la cuestión de la *compatibilidad*  es importante en estos casos.

Comment: Aparte de lo mencionado por A. Cedano, recuerda que todos los atributos html deben estar delimitados, ya sea por comillas dobles o sencillas para garantizar que se interpreten y apliquen correctamente. **Edición:** Cambia los tags de tu pregunta, porque nada tienen que ver con PHP, sino con Javascript y CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo qué es lo que quieres realizar poniendo una imagen en un select, por  sí sólo me parece que no se puede. Sin embargo, te traigo una alternativa para darle más énfasis a cada uno de las opciones del select utilizando **íconos**.

Para ello es necesario utilizar [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) y una librería adicional de Boostrap llamada [boostratp-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), la cual te da muchas funcionalidades para tu select. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de su funcionalidad. Espero te ayude. Bootstrap cuenta con una serie de íconos dentro del framework, [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons) está la lista completa. Si quieres cambiarlos iconos sólo es necesario agregar su nombre en la parte `data-icon="glyphicon-heart"` de dicha `option`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <select class="selectpicker">
      <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">Corazon</option>
      <option data-icon="glyphicon-usd">Dinero</option>
      <option data-icon="glyphicon-user">Usuario</option>
      <option data-icon="glyphicon-lamp" selected>Lampara</option>
    </select>
  </center>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</html>
```